# desc command through code

Tags: java, oracle, toad

Can we get the table description through java code that we get by typing desc in Toad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DatabaseMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) to get the table information.

You can use the `getTablexxx()` and `getColumnxx()` methods to get the table information.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(.....);
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
dbmd.getxxxx();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just get column names,types, precision etc you can use [ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html). [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/SQLstatementResultSetandResultSetMetaData.htm) is an example.

If you want to go beyond this and find out all the constraints, indexes etc defined on the table you can query the corresponding data dictionary views.

Comment: thanks but I need functionalities related to desc and not this.

Answer (score 1):

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','YOUR_TABLE_NAME') 
from dual;
```

It will show you column names,types as well as additional components for creating this table,such as TABLESPACE...;

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_METADATA package or

```
Select * from all_tab_columns where owner=user and table_name='table_name' order by column_id
```